# java vertx jdbc sqlite: how to set PRAGMA syncronous=NORMAL

Tags: java, sqlite, vert.x

Vertx outlines that this is the normal way to connect to a database here https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/ :

```java
String databaseFile = "sqlite.db";

JDBCPool pool = JDBCPool.pool(
    this.context.getVertx(),
    new JDBCConnectOptions()
        .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlite:".concat(databaseFile)),
    new PoolOptions()
        .setMaxSize(1)
        .setConnectionTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
);
```

This application I am writing has interprocess communication, so I want to use WAL mode, and synchronous=NORMAL to avoid heavy disk usage. The WAL pragma (`PRAGMA journal_model=WAL`) is set to the database itself, so I dont need to worry about it on application startup. However, the `synchronous` pragma *is* set per connection, so I need to set that when the appplication starts. Currently that looks like this:

```java
// await this future
pool
  .preparedQuery("PRAGMA synchronous=NORMAL")
  .execute()
```

I can confirm that later on the synchronous pragma *is* set on the database connection.

```java
pool
  .preparedQuery("PRAGMA synchronous")
  .execute()
  .map(rows -> {
    for (Row row : rows) {
      System.out.println("pragma synchronous is " + row.getInteger("synchronous"))
    }
  })
```

and since I enforce a single connection in the pool, this *should* be fine. However I cant help but feel that there is a better way of doing this.

As a side note, I chose a single connection because sqlite is synchronous in nature, there is only ever one write happening at a time to the database. Creating write contention within a single application sounds detrimental rather than helpful, and I have designed my application to have as little concurrent writes within a single process as possible, though inter-process concurrency is real.

Answer (score 0):

So these arent definitive answers, but I have tried a few other options, and want to outline them here.

For instance, vertx can instantiate a SQLClient without a pool:

```java
JsonObject config = new JsonObject()
    .put("url", "jdbc:sqlite:"+databaseFile)
    .put("driver_class", "org.sqlite.jdbcDriver")
    .put("max_pool_size", 1);

Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
SQLClient client = JDBCClient.create(vertx, config);
```

though this still uses a connection pool, so I have to make the same adjustments to set a single connection in the pool, so that the pragma sticks.

There is also a `SQLiteConfig` class from the sqlite library, but I have no idea how to connect that into the vertx jdbc wrappers

```java
org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig config = new org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig();
config.setSynchronous(SynchronousMode.NORMAL);
```

is a pool required with vertx? I did try running the sqlite jdbc driver directly, without a vertx wrapper. But this ran into all kinds of `SQLITE_BUSY` exceptions.